# Comparing backtesting returns with real trading returns

Tags: backtesting, statistics

I have 10 years of backtested simulated performance of some trading strategy (using historical prices), and N months of actual trading performance. What statistical test can I do find out if I'm on target with the backtesting numbers? (both, in terms of expected annual returns and expected annual Sharpe ratio)

Comment: Cross posting your question that fast is generally not considered good taste. Please wait at least a couple of days before reposting on another site.

Answer (score 3):

see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12521/comparing-backtesting-returns-with-real-trading-returns

Comment: I wish @shabbychef would cross-post his answer here.